# Xcode Copying Files on Build Not In App

Tags: ios, xcode

When I Build My App it runs the standard build, but then copies several files that are nowhere in the apps directory.

These files were accidentally added to the app directory when i was making it, but i promptly deleted them.

Is there a way to reset the build process to only consider the current file structure for the app?

Update: The files do not appear in the "Copy" Section of the Build Phase so not sure where they're being referenced in the app itself. Is there a method to hard reset the build process?

Comment: If you select your project file in Xcode and click on your target, there should be a "Build Phases" tab that shows what files are compiled or copied or linked.  Removing ones you don't want from there should clean it up.  (Assuming I understand your question....)

Comment: Or are they just built into the app and you need to clean the build and  delete the built app?

Comment: Wain: I think it's the second case how do I clean the build?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred answer is to clear the build folder using Command-Option-Shift-K and then to choose iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings.

The combination reset the build.

The answer was linked in the comments by @matt